# PDO Ajax updating mysql database

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

I need help in this PHP Ajax updating mysql database using PDO. I wanted to update the database if a user checks the checkbox. Below is my code:

JS:

```
$('input[name=product_new]').click(function(){

    var chkbox_id = $(this).attr('alt');
    var chkbox_selected = $(this).is(':checked');

    if(chkbox_selected == true)
    {
        chkbox_selected = "checked";
    }
    else
    {
        chkbox_selected = "uncheck";
    }


    $.post({
            url: "../products_listing.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {product_id: chkbox_id, product_new: chkbox_selected},
            cache: false,
            success: function(){}

           });

});
```

PHP page with PDO to update database:

```
$id = $_POST['product_id'];
$product_new = $_POST['product_new'];
if(isset($_POST['product_new']))
{
    try
    {
        $query = "UPDATE productinfo SET new_arrival=? WHERE id=?";
        $stmt_new_chkbox = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt_new_chkbox->bindParam(1, $product_new, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt_new_chkbox->bindParam(2, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt_new_chkbox->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

It was working when I use mysql but now I've changed it to use PDO, it won't work anymore. I can't find where went wrong. Thanks in advance guys.

Below is the old code from mysql_:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_id']);
$product_new = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_new']);
if(isset($_POST['product_new']))
{
    $upt_new=mysql_query("update products_list set new_arrival='$product_new' where id='$id'");
}
```

---

Ok! I know what's wrong already. The damn directory path. I took out ../ and it works! Kinda weird though.

Because my js file is in JS folder and products_listing.php is outside of the js folder. Isn't it supposed to be ../products_listing.php?

Can anyone tell me why it's not working which it is supposed to be?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: "it won't work anymore" Is *not* an error message nor a problem description.

Comment: Erm. I know, it won't update the database when I check the checkbox and I can't find any typo or even any error message. I don't know where went wrong.

Comment: Try debugging it. `echo` out some data on the PHP side and `alert` it on the javascript side in the `success` callback. Or call the PHP  directly with those parameters and echo data along the way to find where it's broke.

Comment: You mentioned that you're converting this from `mysql_`.  Congrats!  That's awesome!  Can you show us the *old* code?  Maybe there's something there that didn't translate over right.  At first glance, this code is perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi Charles, I have added the old code from mysql_. As for the Ajax function it's the same. I have tested, the function in ajax is working but somehow when the products_listing page is load, the isset function is not call.

Answer (score 0):

Just split your task into 2 parts: AJAX part and PDO part.

First of all make sure that your PDO part works well. Make a mock $_POST array, and then start playing with PDO calling this script directly, without AJAX. Ask questions here, if something goes wrong. then, as you ret it to work, move to AJAX part, the same way - first, without PDO by just by sending data to server and verifying if it's correct.

Solving 2 problems at once makes things a lot harder. Always split your task into separate parts and solve them one by one.

Comment: Tried it and it really turns out that the isset($_POST['product_new']) is not working. I don't know why but it's working previously and did not missed out anything from the old code too.